# How to change values retrieved from json url in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, parsing

I have a service that retrieves a JSON from an url, I use `ng-repeat` to show values in a list.

My `JSON` looks like this:

```
[
  {"iconuser":"livingroom1","class":"w5","status":"0"},     
  {"iconuser":"meetingroom1","class":"w4","status":"1"}
]
```

How do I replace some values of that object.

example:

`status = 0`  should be `status = OFF`
`status = 1`  should be `status = ON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In native angular:

```
$scope.item = [{"iconuser":"livingroom1","class":"w5","status":"0"}, 
{"iconuser":"meetingroom1","class":"w4","status":"1"}];

angular.forEach($scope.item,, function(obj) {
    if(obj.status === 0)
      obj.status = "OFF";
    else
      obj.status = "ON";

    return obj;   
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, then what should i use to show the new value in my list ? curently i use {{device.status}}   (from device in devices)

Comment: This answer will override the `status` in json to string(`On/Off`), you can still use it as `device.status`. Do you wish to create a new property keeping the original `status` as (`1/0`)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.map` to format your response:

```
var formattedData = responseData.map(function(obj) {
    if (obj.status === 0) {
        obj.status = "OFF";
    } //etc

    return obj;
});
```